# How do I get a random word from a .txt file using C#?

Tags: c#

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int word = 1;
        string FileName;
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        FileStream stream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open);
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I decided to create a "content" string that would contain all the text inside of a .txt file. How do I now select a random word from this string that is not an array?

Comment: I'd say that it depends on how big the file is... if it's not big you can do a split by white space in memory and then use  random index to get a word from resulting list. If the file can be very big, this approach might not be acceptable so you could need to access directly in random positions of the file and look for the first word after that position.

Comment: You're doing async IO incorrectly. You don't need `Task.Run`.

Comment: Well my question is not exactly about async but why am I wrong there?

Comment: Even if your question isn't about async, you should still fix the problem. 1) it'll make your code better and 2) people won't bug you about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split on the spaces and then use random to get a random integer.

```
Random random = new Random();
string[] split = content.Split(" ");
string randomString = split[random.Next(0,split.length)];
```